# How to append jquery div to html correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the input and button in div:

```
<div>
  <input id='input_id_0' value='name'>
  <button type="button" id="remove_id_0"></button>
</div>
```

I'd like to copy the input and the button, increase their id, wrap them in the div and attach after the previous one. So the result should be:

```
<div>
  <input id='input_id_0' value='name'>
  <button type="button" id="remove_id_0"></button>
</div>
<div>
  <input id='input_id_1' value='name'>
  <button type="button" id="remove_id_1"></button>
</div>
```

I wrote the code:

```
    cloneCount = 0;
    cloneCount += 1;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var previousInput = document.getElementById('input_id_' + (cloneCount-1))
    var newInput = $(previousInput)
         .clone(true)
         .attr('id', 'input_id_' + cloneCount)
    previousInput.append(newInput)

    var previousRemoveBtn = document.getElementById('remove_id_' + (cloneCount-1))
    var newRemoveBtn = $(previousRemoveBtn)
         .clone(true)
         .attr('id', 'remove_id_' + cloneCount)

   div.append(newInput)
   div.append(newRemoveBtn)

   $(previousInput).parent().after(div)
```

but that code results in text `object[Object] object[Object]` being appended to my original input. JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Malvinka87/z8t1sxcf/1/

Could you explain to me, please, why that is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jquery, you don't need to use `document.getElementById` or `document.createElement` like that. All of them can be done using jquery:

```js
var input = $('input').clone();
var input_id = input.prop('id');

input_id = input_id.substr(input_id.length - 1, 1);

var button = $('button').clone();
var button_id = button.prop('id');

button_id = button_id.substr(button_id.length - 1, 1);

input.prop('id', 'input_id_' + ++input_id);
button.prop('id', 'remove_id_' + ++button_id);

var div = $('<div>').append(input).append(button);

div.insertAfter('div');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id='input_id_0' value='name'>
  <button type="button" id="remove_id_0">btn</button>
</div>
```

About the id, you can try to get the lastest character from the id string, then increasing it as a number before appending to the new element.